# Delphi: 'GoTo' command does not compile inside 'with'

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

When compiling a piece of code like this:

```
01  function MyGotoDecision: boolean;
02  begin
03    {code ...}
04  end;
05 
06  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
07  label MyLabel;
08  begin
09    with Application do
10    begin
11      {code ...}
12      if MyGotoDecision then
13        goto MyLabel;
14      {more code ...}
15    end;
16    MyLabel:
17      {more code ...}
18  end;
```

I get this strange compiler error message:

```
'Void' does not contain a member named 'MyLabel' at line 13
```

If I remove the 'with' line, the error disappears.

In my real program the 'goto' command will be used to exit from a heavily nested code, where the logic to safely exit is tortuous.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have just found that Delphi is compiling correctly the code. But the message error still is shown in 'Structure view'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Although I don't have the exact same Delphi version as you (I have D6 and D2010 to hand). Can you make an MCVE. Then at least we can see if the problem persists in more modern Delphi versions

Comment: Depends on your real code but can't you remove the `with`? I.e. explicitly qualify anything as needed?

Comment: "In my real program the 'goto' command will be used to exit from a heavily nested code, where the logic to safely exit is tortuous." - clean up the exit logic, use `try/finally` for cleanup, and then you can replace `goto` with `exit`.

Comment: Your edit reveals that the error is actually caused by Error Insight, which is the IDE's kibitz compiler. Error Insight has been buggy since the day it was introduced, and still is to this date in XE8. The solution: Go to Tools->Options->Code Insight and disable it by unchecking the Error Insight box. Voila! No more wrong error messages in the Structure Pane. As far as your "real code*, fix it. There is absolutely no reason to use goto unless you're programming in assembly; there is always a preferable coding option that is cleaner. I have never used goto in nearly 30 years of writing code.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. A friend of mine sent me this link: [link](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=27032). The problem was fixed in later Delphi versions.

Comment: @KenWhite There are good uses of `goto`. The are few and far between. Clearly in languages without structured exception handling `goto` is needed. Even in Delphi there are times when it is useful. The RTL implementation of BobJenkinsHash is a good example. But I do fundamentally agree with you. It seems extremely unlikely that this user should be using `goto`.

Comment: @David: Yes, but clearly Delphi is not a language that doesn't have SEH, and the fact that the EMBT developers did something is hardly evidence there's not a better way or that something should be done. (You complain about their poor choices frequently here in your posts and comments.)

Comment: @Ken In this case the decision is sound

Comment: @David: Clearly, that's a matter of opinion. :-)

Comment: @Ken It's an interesting case. Try and write a version that performs as well, and reads as well, without `goto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have just found that Delphi is compiling correctly the code. But the message error still is shown in 'Structure view'.

Well, that changes things a little then, and explains why I could not reproduce a compiler error.

The tools used by the IDE to parse code are not the same as the tools used to compile it. The tools used by the IDE are known to contain many defects. Clearly you have found one. There's not really any point in submitting a bug report for Delphi 2006. You should simply learn to ignore the error.